# Pandas: Compare rows within groups in a dataframe and create summary rows to mark / highlight different entries in group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with approx. 1200 rows, where some of the rows are duplicated multiple times. The df looks like this:

```
ID  Serial  Age Grade   Chem    Bio   Math  Phy
M001    2   52   37       1      1     1     1
M001    2   55   37 2     1      0     1
M001    3   51   36,5     1      1     1     0
M001    3   51   46,5     1      0     1     1
M041    2   52   36,1     1      1     0     0
M041    2   51   36,1     2      1     2     4
M041    2   52   36,1     1      1     0    
M041    2   52   36,1     1      1     1    
M010    5   58   37,4     0      1     1     3
M010    5   55   39,4     1      2     1     1
M010    5   58   37,4     1      1     1     1
```

The duplicates in the dataframe are supposed to be identified by the ID and Serial column and I was able to do that. However, I would like to compare each group of ID+Serial rows to find where they differ. This is a bit tricky as sometimes there are 2 rows in a group to compare and sometimes the rows (to compare) are more than 2 within each group.

I am interested in a solution where I can groupby the dataframe based on ID and Serial cols and then compare rows within each group. If there is a difference between two or more cells that needs to be recorded (e.g., in a new row with a X below the conflicting cells or perhaps highlighting the cells in red color). The resulting dataframe should look something like this:

```
ID  Serial  Age  Grade  Chem    Bio  Math   Phy
M001    2    52   37      1      1    1      1
M001    2    55   37      2      1    0      1
M001    2    X            X           X 
M001    3    51   36,5    1      1    1      0
M001    3    51   46,5    1      0    1      1
M001    3         X              X           X
M041    2    52   36,1    1      1    0      0
M041    2    51   36,1    2      1    2      4
M041    2    52   36,1    1      1    0 
M041    2    52   36,1    1      1    1 
M041    2    X            X           X      X
M010    5    58   37,4    0      1    1      3
M010    5    55   39,4    1      2    1      1
M010    5    58   37,4    1      1    1      1
M010    5    X    X       X      X           X
```

Can someone help with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a comparison marking table by grouping on `ID` and `Serial` using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get the number of unique entries for each column by [`.nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html).  Mark with `'X'` if number of unique entries > 1 or blank otherwise.

Finally, concat the newly created comparison marking table back to the original dataframe by [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).  Sort by `ID` and `Serial` columns  by [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to bring back the related entries together.

```
df_mark = (df.groupby(['ID', 'Serial'])
             .nunique()
             .gt(1)
             .replace({True: 'X', False: ''})
             .reset_index()
           )

(pd.concat([df, df_mark])
   .sort_values(['ID', 'Serial'])
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Result:

```
      ID  Serial Age Grade Chem Bio Math  Phy
0   M001       2  52    37    1   1    1  1.0
1   M001       2  55    37    2   1    0  1.0
2   M001       2   X          X        X     
3   M001       3  51  36,5    1   1    1  0.0
4   M001       3  51  46,5    1   0    1  1.0
5   M001       3         X        X         X
6   M010       5  58  37,4    0   1    1  3.0
7   M010       5  55  39,4    1   2    1  1.0
8   M010       5  58  37,4    1   1    1  1.0
9   M010       5   X     X    X   X         X
10  M041       2  52  36,1    1   1    0  0.0
11  M041       2  51  36,1    2   1    2  4.0
12  M041       2  52  36,1    1   1    0  NaN
13  M041       2  52  36,1    1   1    1  NaN
14  M041       2   X          X        X    X
```